# Format Legends in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

How can i allocate differnt background colors to the column names entities coming from same column

buidling the tableau dashboard

Its Tableau

I expect differnt color codes

Answer (score 0):

1. set the measureName blue pill on the column shelf;
2. control the meausreName coloring using the mark card drop down for each measure;
3. basically if each column is a measure; 
   you can control the color marks for each measure column.

[image: example color legend per measureName]